# How to resize body when BottomSheet expands

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like the body of my scaffold to change size when the bottom sheet is expanded similar to how the Google Maps app responds when it's bottomsheet is pulled up (the map shrinks to about half the height of the screen).

Comment: Use a `bool` variable to toggle between bodySize1 and bodySize2 and update the `bool` variable whenever you expand the bottom sheet by calling `setState(){}`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What would the widget tree look like?

Answer (score 1):

`body: _isSheetExpanded ? _buildBodySize1() : _buildBodySize2()`

In your `isExpanded()` [or some similar method] for the bottom sheet in expanded state:

```
setState(){
 _isSheetExpanded = true;
}
```

In the `isCollapsed()` method:

```
setState(){
 _isSheetExpanded = false;
}
```